# android record voice to wave file

Tags: android, android-emulator

Thanks for previous replies..

I am doing application to record voice through android to sd card. I used MediaRecorder() to enable mic and record the voice and save it in sd card. This MediaRecorder provides only two options of saving formate (3GPP and MPEG 4). I want to record my file into wave formate, can anyone guide me how to convert audio to wave file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777181/creating-a-wav-file-from-raw-pcm-data-using-the-android-sdk